# BlackBerry EditField specific text in bold

Tags: blackberry

I want to bold specific letters in my EditField.

```
public void changeToBold() {
    try {
        alphaSans = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Sans");
        font = alphaSans.getFont(Font.BOLD, 9, Ui.UNITS_pt);
        editField.setFont(font);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Dialog.alert("alert");
    }
}

public void changeToPlain() {
    try {
        alphaSans = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Sans");
        font = alphaSans.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 9, Ui.UNITS_pt);
        editField.setFont(font);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Dialog.alert("alert");
    }
}
```

I add the text to the EditField from a sqlite db.

```
while(c1.next() && c2.next()) {
            r1 = c1.getRow();
            r2 = c2.getRow();
            temp = r2.getString(0);

            changeToBold();
            theText += temp;
            changeToPlain();
            theText += r.1getString(0);
        }
```

*Maybe there is a way to create a LabelField that holds the text I wnat in bold and then add it simultaneously to the EditField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [RichTextField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RichTextField.html). See [How To - Format text in a RichTextField](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Format_text_in_a_RichTextField.html?nodeid=800679&vernum=0) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, may I another question?
How can I align the title (setTitle()) text to right?

Comment: That is probably best asked in a separate thread, with relevant context.